# Flashing light when pushing bike with (constant) low speed

Tags: dynamo, led-lights

When someone pushes his bike beside him in a constant (low) speed the light will not be at constant (low) brightness, instead it will flash with it's full brightness.

Why does it work like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because the power from a hub dynamo (which technically is a magneto, not a true dynamo) is not clean sine-wave AC but consists of short pulses with alternating polarity. At high speeds these pulses follow each other fast enough that a LED can burn continuously with a small capacitor and a filament bulb does not have time to cool down between pulses.

The effect does not have anything to do with programming or the fact that LED is a diode, and it happens with filament bulbs too. A more complex LED setup could have a capacitor to enable continuous dim light and perhaps even be programmed to flash at low input power, but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: Fillament lamps will glow with AC on either part of its wave.  LEDs don't do that because they're diodes and only let power through in one direction.  Thing I don't know - does the AC frequency change with wheel speed ?

Comment: Dynamos have a fixed set of poles, so when speed changes, the AC frequency changes too. In at least Shimano hub dynamos you can actually feel the poles and see that flashes happen when you cross a pole.

Comment: A LED should not really be connected to a dynamo without any driver circuitry. Voltage regulation is needed unless you want to destroy the LED and filtering capacitor will help its job. Once all that is in place, a full bridge rectifier doesn't add much complexity.

Comment: @Criggie - I would assume that the dynamo contains a full-wave rectifier, so that both sides of the AC cycle get through.

Comment: @DanielRHicks dynamos output AC. They were originally designed for filament bulbs which work fine with AC, and LED lights were later developed to work with existing dynamos. A simple driver circuit can be found here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/161794.

Comment: @ojs - So an alternator in an automobile outputs AC?

Comment: @DanielRHicks yes, they do. I believe it should be clear from context that the question is about bicycle dynamos, which technically are not true dynamos but low power magnetos.

Comment: @ojs -- I haven't worked on an auto alternator for about 30 years, but at that time they all contained the full-wave bridge inside the alternator housing.  There was period when they first came out in the 60s when the bridge was in the separate voltage regulator box, but the VR has been integrated inside the alternator for decades.

Comment: That might well be true, but it's also completely offtopic for bicycles.se. Cars are much more tightly integrated systems so it's completely OK to put the rectifier where it is most convenient. With bicycles you have to design for compatibility with other components, unless you are in monopoly position. Shimano doesn't sell lights at all and SON doesn't have a large market share so they have to play along with existing lights.

Comment: @ojs - Either the unit puts out DC or it puts out AC.  AC would be appropriate to mimic older AC units designed for incandescent bulbs.  DC would be appropriate to mimic older commutator-based DC units, or replace newer units designed for LEDs, et al.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I don't understand what is the point you are trying to make. If you are not sure whether some device that might be a bike dynamo or not outputs AC or DC, I suggest you acquire the device and a multimeter and measure yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If the light is LED and the dynamo has no AC to DC conversion circuit, then the LED should turn on when it gets the right polarity and turn off when it gets the reverse polarity. When the AC frequency is high (which is when the wheel is spinning very fast) the flickering is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a super-capacitor in the system it will need a full charge before permanent full brightness. The electronics may be programmed to switch to bright flashing mode at low voltage and low rpm/speed before the full charge at normal operating voltage and high rpm.

A bright flashing light it is more visible than low brightness permanent light.

Comment: Smells more like the super-cap is missing.